# $.ajax if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I failed to write a condition inside of ajax by using the following syntax.

```
      var num = 1;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
      //condition starts
        if (num === 1){
          url: url1,
          data: data1,
        }else{
          url: url2,
          data: data2,
        }
        //condition finishes
          success: success,
          dataType: dataType
        });
```

but this way works.

```
 var num = 1;
if(num === 1){
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url1,
  data: data1,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
}else{
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url2,
  data: data2,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
}
```

the 2nd method is not quite ideal as repeating my code. 
is my first script in a wrong syntax? Could someone please point out? thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> is my first script in a wrong syntax?

Yes, absolutely. You were just inserting if-else-statement parts in the middle of an object literal. You should use something like this:

```
var params = {
    type: "POST",
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
};
if (num == 1) {
    params.url = url1;
    params.data = data1;
} else {
    params.url = url2;
    params.data = data2;
}
$.ajax(params);
```

Or if you want to inline them, you can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: (num == 1) ? url1 : url2,
    data: (num == 1) ? data1 : data2,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

(If you don't want to repeat the condition, store its boolean result in a variable)

Comment: If you are using the ternary operator (as shown above) and you have multiple data elements, make sure they are contained within curly brackets: data: (num == 1) ? {data1a, data1b, data1c} : {data2a, data2b, data2c},

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this:

```
var num = 1, url, data;

if (num === 1) {
    url = url1;
    data = data1;
} else {
    url = url2;
    data = data2;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The stuff in the `{` braces `}` is an object literal. You can declare it and modify it before you call `$.ajax`.

```
var options =
{
    type: "POST",
    url: url2,
    data: data2,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
};

if (num === 1) { options.url = url; options.data = data; }

$.ajax(options);
```

Answer (score 3):

`$.ajax` takes a regular JavaScript object, so you can fill it in piecewise:

```
request = {type: "POST", success: success, dataType: dataType};
if(num == 1) {
    request.url = url1;
    request.data = data1;
} else {
    request.url = url2;
    request.data = data2;
}
$.ajax(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way if url and data are very simple.

```
  var num = 1;
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url : (num==1? url1 : url2),
      data: (num==1? data1 : data2),
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the condition before the ajax statements and assign common variables there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var num = 1;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: (num === 1 ? url1 : url2)
    data: (num === 1 ? data1 : data2)
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

But as others have mentioned it would be best to just assign variables outside of the ajax call.