# Conditional Statement in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Dygraph object being created:

```
function prime() {
  g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("g"),
      data, //This is the variable I want to avoid passing in for older browsers
      {
      labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
      title: document.getElementById("title").value,
      titleHeight: 35,
      labelsSeparateLines: true,
      includeZero: true
      }
  );
}
```

And I want to have a browser check that determines whether to include the "data" such as:

```
if(Browser.Version() > 8){
  //include data variable
} else{
  //don't include
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas outside of creating a second function to deal with the other case

Comment: Browser sniffing is bad. Avoid.

Comment: Why this test ? What browser feature to you need ?

Comment: @minitech is right, use feature detection instead.

Comment: Pass in `null` or the `data` as `((Browser.Version() > 8) ? data : null)` ?

Comment: whats the value of data when used in other browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [if condition in object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762775/ajax-if-condition)

Comment: How do I test features instead of the browser itself when I'm not too sure which feature it is that I need?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create and manipulate the *object literal* beforehand, or you need to alternate with a ternary operator between *value* and *null / undefined*.

```
var myObj = {
    labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
    title: document.getElementById("title").value,
    titleHeight: 35,
    labelsSeparateLines: true,
    includeZero: true
};

if( Browser.Version() > 8 ) {
    myObj.data = 42;
}
```

or

```
function prime() {
    g = new Dygraph(
     document.getElementById("g"),
      data,
      {
      labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
      title: document.getElementById("title").value,
      titleHeight: 35,
      labelsSeparateLines: true,
      includeZero: true,
      data: Browser.Version() > 8 ? 42 : null
      }
  );
}
```

You might also choose to have a self-invoking function which does the job and returns that object, but thats pretty much the same as example #1. Either way, you can't tell ECMAscript to create or to not-create a key while forming an object literal.

Comment: That thing is called the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and it is a ternary operator.