# How to get the Response from PHP to AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slim-3

To receive the response object from my PHP server I thought you could just put the name of the variable into the `success` function and work on it.
Unfortunately this doesn't work. Is there anything which is wrong with my code? I'm using a framework called Slim 3 for the PHP server.

This is my AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://server/authenticate",
    contentType : "application/json",                                                  
    data: '{"username":"' + username + '", "password":"' + password + '"}',     
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(response)             // response is not defined
        console.log(response.status)      // response is not defined
        console.log("Test")               // Works!
        console.debug(data)               // Nothing, blank line 
        console.debug(data.status)        // undefined       
    }
});
```

My PHP function:

```
public function authenticate($request, $response)
{             
    ...

    return $response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Set-Cookie', $token);
    //return $response;

}
```

In general my `success` function works but I wanted to put an `if` inside it to really check that the statuscode is `200`. But as I showed above, there comes undefined.
And if I check my browser via F12, I can see that the status code gets transmitted correctly, e.g. `200`.

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data.status == 200) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: My experience is you have to `echo` the response from PHP, which will send the data to the stdout, which in the case of a web request is back to the client.  As far as 'response' being undefined in your success method, you are not passing that variable into it...

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762816/1527252) You are attempting to insert an `if` statement inside of an object literal.

Comment: Please add a `console.log(data)`

Comment: Just in your php function, do echo json_encode($response) and you will be able to get the status from ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to return a JSON object from a PHP array:

```
$content = ["foo" => 'bar', ...] ; //Any data you wish to return
return $response->withJson($content);
```

Comment: This is closer to useful. I would make it explicitly clear that `$content` should be an array because I don't think OP understands JSON/Ajax.

Comment: `$content = array('name' => 'Bob', 'status' => 40);
return $response->withJson($content);`

Comment: @bassxzero Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `withJson()`, your response is converted to a valid json-response, and it also automatically sets the PHP header for you.

From the documentation,

> The Content-Type of the Response is automatically set to `application/json;charset=utf-8`.

This means that, as long as the variable you pass to `withJson()` is an array, that method should be all you need - you don't have to worry about setting headers or json-encoding any further, as such

```
$data = array(...);
return $response->withJson($data);
```

- https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#returning-json

Comment: This answer is fine in logic but you'll have to adapt this to your framework

Comment: Answer is not "fine". https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html He is using slim. It automatically adds headers if you use it correctly and you don't need to echo the response, the frame handles sending the response.

Comment: If you use `withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');`, or set the header yourself, it's pretty much the same thing. `withJson()` or `json_encode()` is also achieves same result. But if the frame sends the response, you can return it instead of printing it.

Comment: @Qirel Yes, "it's pretty much the same thing", but using the JSON form of the response gives you access to helper methods that the normal response doesn't have. It also aromatically runs `json_encode` for you.

Comment: @bassxzero I must admit; I haven't used Slim. After reading the documentation, I'll admit, those methods make it easier to work with - simply doing `return withJson(..)` should be sufficient, as that sets the header too. My answer originally assumed pure PHP, without any framework. Either way, the old answer would have *worked*, as it in the end achieves the same - but this is simpler and takes advantage of what the framework provides.

Comment: @bassxzero As I wrote "you'll have to adapt this to your framework"