# Ajax call uri for different url if condition

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I tried to create an ajax call POST url depend on the text input field from json response, here the current my ajax post

```
<script>
    $('#MyForm').submit(function(e){
        var service_type2 = document.getElementById('type').value;
        if(service_type2=== 'post'){
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: services/post.php,
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: success
        });
        }else{
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: services/pre.php,
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: success
        });

        }
        .done(function(data){

            // show the response

            $('#success__params').html("You data will be saved");

        })
        .fail(function() {

            // just in case posting your form failed
             alert( "Posting failed." );

        });
        e.preventDefault();

        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
        return false;

    });
</script>
```

If the input text value for #service has a value response "post", thank the first URL will execute (vice versa).

Tried using a buttons not working, and I tried above code but the page keep refresh, any suggestion? I tried following this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762775/ajax-if-condition), but still not working

Sorry for bad english :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a variable name mismatch:

```
var service_type2 = document.getElementById('type').value;
if(service_type2 === 'post'){ // service_type2, not type
```

And you must to pass a string (wrapped by quotes) to the `url` property: `url: 'services/post.php'`

And `success` property must be a function

```
success: function(data){
  // show the response
  $('#success__params').html("You data will be saved");
},
```

You probably have to remove `.done()` and `fail()` and add `error` property

```
error: function() {
  // just in case posting your form failed
  alert( "Posting failed." );
}
```

Final code:

```
<script>
    $('#MyForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var service_type2 = document.getElementById('type').value;
        if(service_type2 === 'post'){
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "services/post.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
              // show the response
              $('#success__params').html("You data will be saved");
            },
            error: function() {
              // just in case posting your form failed
              alert( "Posting failed." );
            }
          });
        }else{
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "services/pre.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
              // show the response
              $('#success__params').html("You data will be saved");
            },
            error: function() {
              // just in case posting your form failed
              alert( "Posting failed." );
            }
          });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @fiter, I edit my question following your suggestion but still same, page reloading and not hit the URI :(

Comment: which version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: Wow!!! mate thanks a lot, it's working well. Big thanks, I has been struggling with this almost a week :(. Big thank